# Adding Metadata of image as band when band has different projection than image?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, metadata, multi-band

I am trying to add `system:time_start` as a band in my image, so that when I mosaic the image collection, I retain the time value of each pixel. I am doing this in Landsat data. However, when I add the metadata, it gets added as EPSG:4326 as opposed to EPSG:32644, which is the projection of a Landsat image.

[image]

I have attached the screenshot that shows time is added in a different projection. This is especially troublesome when I try to export the image--all I get is straight lines.

below is a reproducible code

https://code.earthengine.google.com/179ddb6096f79bd45c10930b0b6fbcca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a new image band to have the same [projection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/projections) as an existing band, you can use the existing band as the base for the calculation. In the following example, the single-band `base_band` image will have the same projection (and extent and mask) as the band `B1`. You then can use the `base_band` to construct a `time` band that retains the same projection.

```js
function timer(kmg) {
  var time_start = kmg.metadata('system:time_start');
  var base_band = kmg.select('B1').multiply(0);
  var time_band = base_band.add(
      time_start.divide(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)
    ).rename('time');
  return kmg.addBands(time_band); 
}
```